MAUI Build fails with "Error loading Entitlements.plist template" after upgrading test device to iOS 18
After upgrading one of my test devices to iOS 18 and the associated XCode update, I ran into the following build issue. The devices running iOS 17.x continue to build with no issues.
Error loading Entitlements.plist template '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.5.sdk

I fixed this by adding an empty Entitlements.plist file under Platforms > iOS.
Note by "empty" I mean still valid, but empty:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
</dict>
</plist>

